# How to set value like HTML in Flutter CheckboxListTile?

Tags: flutter

In HTML, checkbox has name, value and label:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="fruit" name="fruits" value="small_apple"><label for="fruit">Small Apple</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="fruit" name="fruits" value="big_apple"><label for="fruit">Big Apple</label>
```

If both are checked, I will get an array named fruits which contains "small_apple" and "big_apple" once submitted.

Flutter CheckboxListTile has a title which appear on screen:

```
CheckboxListTile(
    title: Text("Small Apple"),
    value: value,
    onChanged: (bool value) { ... },
)
```

I do not need "Small Apple" to be sent on submit, but "small_apple".
"value" in Flutter keeps checkbox state(true/false) only, so how can I set "value" like HTML in Flutter? Or do I have to convert "Small Apple" to "small_apple" before submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can declare a String `String stringValue;` and inside your onChanged callback you can set the needed value for each checkbox
For example for the small_apple checkbox just add

```
onChanged:(ischecked){
stringValue = "small_apple" ;
value= ischecked;
}
```

And then do the same thing for the other checkbox,
Now you must have to set the checkbox value inside the OnChanged **And Call setState** so the UI state of your checkbox changes

Comment: I got the idea. Thanks!:)